# How can I get normal shading on a SKSpriteNode with a custom shader?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, fragment-shader

I've been doing some work in SpriteKit, and I can't seem to get custom shaders and the pseudo 3D lighting effects from a normal texture to work at the same time.

I have a pair of PNG textures, representing a shape with its basic coloring, and a normal map of the same image. If I create an SKSpriteNode, using those textures and add a light to the scene, I see the bumpiness and beveled edges I expect.

[image]

```
cactus = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Saguaro.png")
cactus.normalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Saguaro_n")
cactus.position = sceneCenter
cactus.lightingBitMask = 1

light = SKLightNode()
light.position = CGPoint.zero
light.lightColor = UIColor.white
light.isEnabled = true
light.categoryBitMask = 1
light.ambientColor = UIColor.white
light.falloff = 0.3
```

If, however, I add a custom shader, I get the flat color of just the colors in the texture image. (Code below)

[image]

```
// Assign a shader to the SpriteNode
// Shader loaded from a file with code below
cactus.shader = myShader

// Shader code
void main(void) {    
    gl_FragColor = SKDefaultShading();
}
```

Is there something I can do in the shader to use the built-in lighting effects from the normal map? I'm not too familiar with writing custom fragment shaders, so perhaps there's something obvious I'm not doing.

Comment: May I ask why you need to specify a custom shader if it has the desired effect out of the box?

Comment: I was looking into using a custom shader to do coloring of textures, i.e., so I could make one image in grayscale and color it at runtime using a shader. That way, I could ship a smaller application, and have more interesting coloring options.

It seems like how SpriteKit works is that if the code specifies using a texture map, the Apple provided shader is used, but assigning a different shader will override the default one, thus losing that functionality. The answer is to implement a shader that has light position in the uniform data, and write the lighting engine myself. C'est la vie.